Error When Update Mahasiswa Data : Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
I use protected
$primaryKey = 'NIM'; public $incrementing = false; protected $keyType = 'string';
(In Mahasiswa Model)
it's already fine when store/add data to database but when i want to update the data, it's alwasys error.
You can check at this :
https://github.com/Uniclowns/tugas-praktikum-8/issues/1
I had tried to 'NIM' => 'nullable|string|max:16|unique:mahasiswas,NIM,'.$this->mahasiswa->NIM but still error

On the controller you received model as a parameter Mahasiswa $mahasiswa which by default will look for the data by id (which you don't have) that is why you're getting Unknown column id error.
On resources/views/mahasiswa/edit.blade.php you pass $mahasiswa->NIM, so you could change your update method on your controller as:
    public function update(Request $request, $mahasiswa) : RedirectResponse
    {
        $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::where('NIM', $mahasiswa)->findOrFail();

        $firstData = [
            'NIM' => 'required|string|max:16|unique:mahasiswas,NIM,' . $mahasiswa->NIM,
            'nama' => 'required|string|max:250',
            'jurusan' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'prodi' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'alamat' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'ttl' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'no_hp' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];

        $validated = $request->validate($firstData);

        $mahasiswa->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('mahasiswas.index')->withSuccess('Data Mahasiswa is updated successfully');
    }

